# iReport / JasperReports pagination and values problems

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am designing a simple enough report using iReport 4.5.0. It's a header/detail affair, A4 size.

The detail part of the report is a sub-report, which has a detail section of height 19, a page footer of height 1, and the report height is therefore set to 20.

Sample 1 here shows the first page:

[image: Sample 1]

Everything down to the bottom of the column header boxes is in the main report page header section. The line underneath the detail part is in the page footer, as is everything below it. The vertical lines marking the columns in the detail part are in the sub-report along with the line values.

Sample 2 is a few pages in. Note the two problems -

[image: Sample 2]

Why is there suddenly a line across the detail section, i.e. why has the sub-report decided to start a new page there? Float Column Footer and Ignore Pagination settings in the sub-report don't affect this.

Secondly, why are the values in the page footer suddenly null ?

EDIT - JRXML as requested (logos and some other confidential stuff removed).

[Main report](http://pastie.org/3255410)

[Detail sub-report](http://pastie.org/3255429)

Comment: It is better if you post the both jrxml file (may be the light version)

Comment: I've edited the question to include Pastie links - not sure what you mean by 'the light version'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a data issue - duplication in the table that main report is based on.